# Where should we place core extensions or extensions to gems in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Our Rails 4 application includes a module that adds a method to a class in the `geoip` gem, following the pattern documented [here](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/). Currently, that extension is in the lib/extensions/ directory:

```
#lib/extensions/geoip_extensions.rb
module GeoipExtensions
  module GeoIP
    module City
      def location_name
        [city_name, real_region_name, country_name].reject(&:blank?).join(', ')
      end
    end
  end
end

GeoIP::City.include GeoipExtensions::GeoIP::City
```

```
#config/initializers/extensions/geoip.rb
require 'geoip_extensions'
```

In Rails 5, is `lib/extensions` still the appropriate place for extensions to gems or to core classes, or should this be converted to a `concern`?

Comment: I would argue that concerns are something different – mainly code fragments that can be re-used in several classes. Therefore for extensions to external libraries I would still use the `lib` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails concerns are a convenient way to share and test reusable code across models, controllers, and other classes. Because the primary use is making class and instance methods (and scopes, before and after filters, etc) reusable, they're probably an unnecessary abstraction if you just want to add a method to a single class. For your use case, `lib/extensions` is still completely reasonable in Rails 5.

Comment: Thank you - that was the gut-check I needed.